# Dropdown Menu CSS and Select tag in Chrome Ubuntu

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, ubuntu, web

Hello everyone I have got some problems would like to as all of you!

I have made a dropdown menu in CSS and make a Select tag option below the menu but when I try to select some of the option in select tag the sub-menu of dropdown menu shown up. I don't want the sub-menu shown up.

Do you have any idea to do it? 
Below is my code

CSS:

```
ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*Link Appearance*/
ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #666;
    padding: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
ul#menu li {
    position: relative;
}
/*sub menu*/
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="s.css">
</head>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
            </ul></li>

    </ul>
    <select name="Denomination" tabindex="0" title="" alt="">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>

    </select>
</html>
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: your code is working fine in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/RKTBV/ which browser you have this issue?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: Chrome in OS Ubuntu. You can try to click on some option of them. For mine, I click on option 4 and the sub-menu up of dropdown menu shown up!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, of course. Chrome tries to restore hover state after the select option click event. This process runs after the change event, so you can prevent the anomaly with a little trick with a global class and `setTimeout()`.

Check my answer to the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894645/choosing-select-option-opens-the-dropdown-menu/25939650).