# HTML select triggers css:hover on select

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu, hover

I have a menu with collapsible sub items and under the menu there is a dropdown/select box. On choosing an option from the select box, the menu item that is at the same position vertically with mouse pointer gets triggered with CSS :hover

Here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/a8ve1vj9/

The DOM is the same as in my actual case, and the CSS rules come from different CSS files that are included, so this is why you may see some rules getting repeated (ie grid, global, etc)

```
<div id="menu">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col_12">
                    <ul class="fullMenu">
                        <li><a href="">example3</a>
                           <ul class="sub">
                                <li><a href="">submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">submenu2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">submenu3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">submenu4</a></li>
                            </ul></li>
                        <li><a href="">example4</a> <ul class="sub">
                                <li><a href="">submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">submenu2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">submenu3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">submenu4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">example5</a>
                            <ul class="sub">
                                <li><a href="">submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">submenu2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">submenu3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">submenu4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="search">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col_12">
                    <div class="col_4  m_col_12 s_col_12">
                        <label>choose option</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col_8 m_col_12 s_col_12">
                        <div class="select">
                            <select>
                              <option value="">option1</option>
                              <option value="">option2</option>
                              <option value="">option3</option>
                              <option value="">option4</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i examined the dublicate question proposed, and indeed seems pretty much similar to mine..the case is, that in the other question, there is not a "clean" solution as well, but at least there is one...so would it be suggested, to follow that proposed solution, or should this be reported as a bug at least on chromium based browsers? is it actually a bug issue afterall?

EDIT

js fix solution

```
$("select").on("change", function(){$(".sub").hide(); $("#select-form").submit();});
```

contributed by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1193536/jack-dimas

Comment: Looks fine in chrome..

Comment: i m running it on chrome, and on firefox and on selecting option1 or option2 etc.. the menu on top gets displayed

Comment: also on canary same issue on my side

Comment: tested also on IE 11 - does work - you may want to provide a snapshot?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2q3au3883i8w5d/snapshot.png?dl=0 here is a snapshot

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili that's the issue i m having as well.. almost similar.. i didn't come with a result during my search..incorrect keywords perhaps..

Comment: yes it's a bug, it's OK, I saw that question before and remembered it and I searched for it now ;))

Comment: it would be nice if we could have a "clean" solution

Comment: @F.Müller did you manage to reproduce it with the snapshot given?

Comment: js fix solution
$("select").on("change", function(){$(".sub").hide(); $("#select-form").submit();});
contributed by http://stackoverflow.com/users/1193536/jack-dimas